# Thinktecture Identity Server v/s WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, federated-identity, identityserver3, wso2-identity-server

Am trying to choose between Thinktecture Identity Server v3 and Wso2 identity server for implementing Identity and Access Management solution.

Particularly, am interested in using following features:

- Single Sign-On (SSO)
- Managing user identities
- Connecting to central repository like Active Directory, OpenLdap, Oracle Internet Directory etc.
- Active and Passive Federation
- Integration with ADFS

We are a .Net based shop, so getting more inclined to Thinktecture's IS, but don't want to rule out WSO2 just because its Java (one more dependency for us)

Are there other Pros/Cons between the two?

Thanks

Comment: Never used Wso2 but IS does all the above with limited user provisioning and only authenticates against a SQL DB.

Comment: I'm an enthusiastic IS user as it is fully featured, highly configurable, and has an active development group. Be aware that it is typically configured in code (programmer required), rather than being an out-of-the-box solution that IT folks would configure. Not sure if WSO2 is different.

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the developer of WSO2 Identity server. So my answer would biased to our product :)

WSO2IS is comprehensive Identity Management platform - having support for SAML2, OpenID, XACML 3.0, OAuth 2.0, OpenID Connect, SCIM, WS-Security standards.

And it acts as an Enterprise Identity Bus (EIB) — a central backbone to connect and manage multiple identities regardless of the standards on which they are based (http://blog.facilelogin.com/2014/10/identity-federation-patterns-with-wso2.html).

Few unique features that I would like to highlight on WSO2 Identity Server are.

1. SSO bridging to make identity and entitlement management effortless.
2. Identity Federation with EIB concept.(http://blog.facilelogin.com/2014/10/wso2-identity-server-microsoft-adfs.html)
3. Seamless integration between internal applications and cloud apps
   such as Salesforce, Google Apps, and Microsoft Office 365.
4. New user and group provisioning capabilities
   (http://blog.facilelogin.com/2014/10/wso2-identity-server-500-provisioning.html)
5. Multi-option and multi-step authentication to provide flexibility in
   selecting authentication options and enable robust multi-factor
   authentication
   (http://blog.facilelogin.com/2014/10/what-is-new-in-wso2-identity-server-500.html)
6. High scalability (We have a middle-east customer using WSO2 IS over
   an user base of 4 million for OpenID support.)
7. Light-weight and Very low memory footprint. The stripped down
   version of WSO2 IS can be started with 64MB Heap Size and the
   standard versions runs with 96MB Heap.
8. Highly extensible. The architecture behind WSO2 IS is highly
   extensible. You can easily plugin your authenticators, user store,
   provisioning connectors etc...
9. Support for multi-tenancy.
10. Suport for multiple user stores (AD, LDAP, JDBC)
11. Interoperability.
12. Part of a proven SOA product platform provided by WSO2.